# cross validation matlab toolbox issue

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics, cross-validation, toolbox

```
Labels=[1; 0];
k=5; 
groups = Labels;
cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', groups, k);
```

I am getting error of no bio informatics toolbox.
Is there a way I could rewrite this function without using crossvalind?

Comment: Here's a copy from someone's repo on Github: http://github.com/stevetjoa/ccrma/blob/master/crossvalind.m